# Authorize only email from specific domain asp.net MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, authorization

I'm trying to limit access to one controller to users from one specific domain. I thought the following would work :

```
[Authorize(Users = "*@domain.com")]
```

But it doesn't. Is there a way to do this out of the box or I need to develop my own attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created an attribute that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class AuthorizeEmailDomainAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        // Custom property
        public string EmailDomain { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!isAuthorized)
            {
                return false;
            }

            bool isGoodDomain= httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Contains("@" + EmailDomain);
            return isGoodDomain;
        }
    }
```

Have a nice day